# What's the meaning of backticks after gql and styled.div

Tags: javascript, styled-components, gql

I was looking for documentation of Graphql client `Apollo`, here I've got that the query is a string but inside backticks, what does the `gql` prefix means before the query string? My question is regarding the syntax

```js
import { useQuery, gql } from '@apollo/client';

const EXCHANGE_RATES = gql`
  query GetExchangeRates {
    rates(currency: "USD") {
      currency
      rate
    }
  }
`;
```

I've seen same type of syntax for styled components.

```js
import { styled } from "@styles";

export const Content = styled.div`
  text-transform: none;
  font-size: ${props => props.theme.typography.h4FontSize};
  text-align: center;
  vertical-align: center;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  flex-direction: column;
`;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This type of functions is called "[tag functions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals#Tagged_templates)". They are not magical, but certainly somewhat advanced.

There are also couple of native tag functions (like [String.raw](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/raw)).

All tag functions only work with template strings.